# Why viewWillTransitionToSize pass wrong size in?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, ios8

I adjust a constraint in a iOS8 rotation delegate method, but size is not the same what I can see on device, why?

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    println("size: \(size)")
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    widthConstraint.constant = (size.width / 8.0) - 4.0
}
```

`size: (1024.0,768.0)`

But real size is smaller then full iPad size.

Testing on real device, and viewController is an embedded container view controller.

It seems in somehow I get the parentViewController's view size.

[image]

Comment: this method return just the device size not the container/view size

Comment: API: *Notifies the container that the size of its **view** is about to change.*

Comment: “View controllers forward the size change message to their views and child view controllers"

Comment: interesting, where hove you found it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:

Comment: you can "send" others size to the child controller if in the Parent controller are you using for example this:   ` override func sizeForChildContentContainer(container: UIContentContainer, withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
               var size : CGSize
        //size = CGSizeMake(100.0, parentSize.height);
        size = CGSizeMake(100.0, 100);
        return size
    } `

Comment: observed the same problem, and I think it is a system bug or system cannot decide the accurate size for some reason. Especially when setup a split view controller structure.